# Android element is hidden under bottom dock

Tags: android, xml, layout

So I just created a new basic activity:

`activity_chat.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.nika.chatapp.Chat">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_chat" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`content_chat` is a layout inside coordinator layout which has
`height="match_parent"` and I have an element at the bottom of it and it's
hidden beneath bottom deck.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

`content_chat.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.nika.chatapp.Chat"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_chat">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: activity_chat.xml]

[image: content_chat.xml]

Comment: Why don't you use a LinearLayout for you're parent Layout ?

Comment: run it on device and see result.

Comment: @primaëlquemerais I use coordinator layout for ToolBar, relative layout for showing edit text at the bottom of screen.

Comment: 'Cause it looks like the LinearLayout is placed just under your Relative one :/

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin It does same on the device (nexus 5)

Comment: Just a guess - but perhaps it has to do with how views are brought in via `include`. Perhaps try setting your `app:layout_behavior` on the `<include />` tag

Comment: @Nick put the include tag before the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin That didn't help

Comment: @Nick remove the `layout_behavior` and replace it with `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Nice! Thank you. It solved everything.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from the `RelativeLayout` in `content_chat.xml`

Also as another commenter noted, you will want to add a top-margin to your `RelativeLayout` via `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`, so it plays nicely with the `AppBarLayout`

Comment: Thank you. It did really work. But now included layout is crossing AppBar.

Comment: As per comment from @Rod_Algonquin, look at adding a margin for the AppBar at the top

Comment: Edit answer to include his contribution.